# understanding floating point representation of 2^x

Tags: floating-point

I got a function that compute a floating point representation of 2^x. I do understand most of its part, however I am facing some confusion on the nested if-else statement of this function:

```
/* Compute 2**x */
float fpwr2(int x) {

  unsigned exp, frac;
  unsigned u;

  if (x < -149) {
  /* Too small. Return 0.0 */
     exp = 0;
     frac = 0;
  } else if (x < -126) {
  /* Denormalized result */
     exp = 0;
     frac = 1 << (x + 149);
  } else if (x < 128) {
  /* Normalized result. */
     exp = x + 127;
     frac = 0;
  } else {
  /* Too big. Return +oo */
     exp = 255;
     frac = 0;
  }
  u = exp << 23 | frac;
  return u2f(u);
}
```

my question is, why those particular numbers (-149,-126,128) are chosen? If, I am computing the 64bit floating point representation of 2^x, are those number changed? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the definition of a [single-precision floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format).

The range of -126 to 127 is the exponent that can be encoded in the format. Anything less than -126 will be denormalized because there won't be enough bits in the fraction part, and anything greater than 127 (i.e. `>= 128`) can't be represented at all.

There are 23 bits available in the fraction part, so a denormalized value can be between 2^(-126 - 1) and 2^(-126 - 23). -126 - 23 = -149.

Yes the values will change with a [64-bit floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) - the exponent ranges from -1022 to 1023, and there are 52 bits in the fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Those numbers are based on 32-bit floating point representation, which has 8 bits of exponent, 23 bits of mantissa, and 1 bit of sign.  This allows the exponent to range from -126 to 127 (-127 is used for denormalized numbers), but you have to add 127 to it to get it to the unsigned value used in bit arithmetic.  When you allow denormalizing, you can get smaller numbers by shifting the value in the mantissa; since there are 23 mantissa bits, this allows you to go down to an exponent of -126-23 = -149.

If you're doing 64-bit floating point, you should increase these based in the size of the corresponding fields. E.g. if it's 16 bits of exponent and 47 bits of mantissa, they would be -65581, -65534, and 65535.